# Erro ao tentar gerar uma APK assinada

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-manifest

Erro ao tentar gerar uma APK assinada. Já gerei a keystore, passwords, alias, etc.

> Error:(32) Error: The  element must be a direct child of
>   the  root element [WrongManifestParent]
>            element should be defined as a direct child of the 
>    tag, not the  tag or an  tag.
>   Similarly,    a  tag must be declared at the root level, and
>   so on. This check    looks for incorrect declaration locations in the
>   manifest, and complains if    an element is found in the wrong place. 
>   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html
>   1 errors, 0 warnings Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
>
> > Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target. To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your
> >     build script as follows: ... android {
> >         lintOptions {
> >             checkReleaseBuilds false
> >             // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
> >             // but continue the build even when errors are found:
> >             abortOnError false
> >         } } ...

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="projeto.projeto_app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <!-- Allows the API to use the Global Positioning System (GPS) to determine the device's location to within a very small area. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- Allows the API to use WiFi or mobile cell data (or both) to determine the device's location. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:name=".util.ApplicationUtils"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        <!-- Google Play Services -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <!-- Maps V2 -->
        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />

        <!--
         API Key (Coloque a sua aqui)
         https://console.developers.google.com
        -->
        <!--
             <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyC2TrJso03M7qRrBm7GnWvq_Y_0jaL5N40" />
        -->

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCwtsvnPsAmjnjGh9qejAgzaU4R6_uvoX8"/>

        <!-- botão de login facebook -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <!-- Main activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Map activity -->

        <!-- Facebook activity -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.BaseActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <!-- Keeper activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ContatoActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <!-- Registrar activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.RegistrarActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>

        <!-- Rota activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.AcomActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activity.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Map activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MaActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>

        <!-- Prevenção activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.PrevActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Henrique, acredito que o problema possa ser a tag `<uses-feature>` estar dentro de `<application>` ao invés de ser filha direto de `<manifest>`, mas não tenho certeza...

Comment: @Wakim Eu resolvi dessa forma, retirando ela de dentro do application. Não tive tempo de postar. Caso queira colocar como resposta, eu marco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesse caso, o correto seria remover a tag `<uses-feature>` de dentro de `<application>` e colocar como filho direto da tag `<manifest>`.